# Get file contents from ProjectItem in Visual Studio 2015 extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, vsx, projectitem

Is it possible to access the contents of a `ProjectItem` object? Is there an alternative for going via `ProjectItem.Properties` and read the contents from the `FullPath`?

Comment: @ Could you check th documents which shared information about how to use the Projectitem? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.projectitem.filenames?view=visualstudiosdk-2017 and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ys81cc94.aspx